# Show that $g(s):=(\beta -\alpha)^{-1}\int _{\alpha }^{\beta }f(\frac{x}{s})dx$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x+1)=f(x), \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Given $\alpha < \beta$, define the function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $g(s):=(\beta -\alpha)^{-1}\int _{\alpha }^{\beta }f\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)dx$ if $s \ne 0$ and $g(0)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$. Show that the function $g$ is continuous.

---

I know that since $f(x+1)=f(x), \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is periodic. Using this fact how do I show that $\int _{\alpha }^{\beta }f\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)dx$ is continuous on $(0,1]$?

Comment: I guess you mean $g(s)$, not $g(x)$ right?

Comment: Yes! Exactly, edited.

Comment: Continuity for $s\neq 0$ is straightforward. The difficulty is for $s=0$.

Comment: I don't see why it is straightforward :/.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is periodic and continuous, it is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose for any given $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$
|f(t)-f(r)|<\varepsilon\quad\textrm{if   }|r-t|<\delta.
$$
Given $s_0>0$, we can pick $s$ close enough to $s_0$ in such a way that
$$
|x||1/s-1/s_0|<\delta
$$
for all $x\in[\alpha,\beta]$ (for that it is enough to choose $\max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}|1/s-1/s_0|<\delta$). With that choice
$$
|f(x/s)-f(x/s_0)|<\varepsilon
$$
for all $x\in[\alpha,\beta]$. Then $|g(s)-g(s_0)|<\varepsilon$ as well.